# AWS Glue Job Python Script Boto3 - want to hide credentials

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

Has anyone found a way to hide boto3 credentials in a python script that gets called from AWS Glue?

Right now I have my key and access_key embedded within my script, and I am pretty sure that this is not good practice...

Comment: Is the machine where you run the Python script an EC2 instance?

Comment: It's basically a job that I've set up via the GUI in AWS Glue.  It appears to be a virtual EC2 instance per stuff in my logs:

172.ec2.internal:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1506614239354_0001/glue-assembly.jar
17/09/28 15:59:43 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/tmp/glue-default.conf -> hdfs://ip-172-31-4-172.ec2.internal:8020/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1506614239354_0001/glue-default.conf

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer! When I established the IAM role for my Glue services, I didn't realize I was opening that up to boto3 as well.

The answer is that I don't need to pass my credentials.  I simply use this:

```
mySession = boto3.Session(region_name='my_region_name')
```

and it works like a charm!

Comment: Are you using the included boto3 library, or did you have to import your own? I am having trouble connecting to ecs to trigger a task using boto3 and I'm curious if it's because the included library is outdated.

Comment: I do explicitly call the import boto3 library.

Comment: I misspoke, I meant were you including the boto library as an external library in glue, but that was not my problem anyway. The problem I was  having had to do with connecting to a redshift db and trying to trigger an ecs task. Turns out I needed a NAT gateway on my redshift subnet.